# Find Carriage Returns in Files Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to see all the instances of files containing the Windows-style `crlf` instead of Unix-style `lf` in a set of files. Here's what I have so far:

```
sls -Path src/*.cs -Pattern "`r`n" | group Path | select name
```

This works if I search for any normal text, but it's not finding the carriage returns, even though (according to everything I can find online) that's the proper Powershell escape sequence for carriage returns and newlines. For the record `\r\n` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sls` (an alias for `Select-String`) works line by line, so it's already processing (consuming) the line breaks during the file reading process before it gets to the regex matching.

Use something that reads the entire file, and then look for it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path src/*.cs | ForEach-Object {
    $contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)
    if ($contents -cmatch '\r\n') {
        $_
    }
} | Group-Object Directory | Select-Object Name
```

`\r\n` is used here instead of the backticks because you're escaping them for the regex engine, not for powershell.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that PS v3 and above support the simpler `Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw` for something like `GCI src/*.cs | ?{(GC $_.FullName -Raw) -match '\r\n'} | Group Directory | Select Name`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yeah it's a good point, and I usually do, I was just in a rush. Feel free to edit!

Comment: I have no issue using ``"`r`n"`` with something like `-replace` or `-match`

Comment: @Matt not saying it won't work, I just like to keep the regex consistent; it helps when working with regex testers or sharing them because it's more "portable" I guess? I prefer single quotes for regex when possible too, so that lets me keep using those.

Comment: True. I only put the quotes there anyway for the code markup.